# Is the Prouhet-Thue-Morse constant transcendental in any integer base $b>2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, transcendental-number-theory

I have asked the following question on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150310/is-the-prouhet-thue-morse-constant-transcendental-in-any-integer-base-b2) some time ago and offered a bounty, yet received no answers nor comments, so I'm posting it here.

---

The Prouhet-Thue-Morse constant, defined as

$$
\tau =\sum _{{i=0}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {t_{i}}{2^{{i+1}}}}=0.412454033640\ldots 
$$

where the $t_i$ are elements of the Thue-Morse sequence, is transcendental. But is

$$
\tau_b =\sum _{{i=0}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {t_{i}}{b^{{i+1}}}}
$$

also transcendental, for $b>2$?

Comment: Did you try to adapt  the proof for the transcendence of $\tau$ to $\tau_b$?

Comment: No, as I was hoping there were already results of that nature available

Comment: I believe there are papers of Allouche that address this. I will try to check later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michel Waldschmidt, [Words and transcendence](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00407221/file/WordsTranscendence.pdf), writes in Section 3.1, on page 461, "Mahler also proved in 1929 that the so-called Prouhet–Thue–Morse–Mahler number in base $g\ge2$, given by $$\xi_g=\sum_{n\ge0}{a_n\over g^n}$$
  where $(a_n)_{n\ge0}$ is the Prouhet–Thue–Morse sequence, is transcendental; see [52] and [15, Section 13.4]." [15] is Allouche and Shallit, Automatic sequences: Theory, Applications, Generalizations (Cambridge
University Press, 2003). [52] is K. Nishioka, Mahler Functions and Transcendence (Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1631, Springer- Verlag, 1996).

Waldschmidt gives "the idea of proof," and refers to [15, Section 13.4] and [52, Example 1.3.1] for the full proof.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot!